# FileNotFoundException running JBehave (Maven Project, IntelliJ)

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jbehave

Firstly, I'd like to say that I'm a .Net developer who's temporarily working on a java project. I'm very familiar with SpecFlow and it seems that JBehave is very similar.

I'm trying to get a basic story to run in my project, but everything I try to do seems to fail with the same exception

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Source\DataLoader\target\jbehave\storyDurations.props (The system cannot find the file specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:55)
at org.jbehave.core.reporters.TemplateableViewGenerator.storyDurations(TemplateableViewGenerator.java:123)
at org.jbehave.core.reporters.TemplateableViewGenerator.generateReportsView(TemplateableViewGenerator.java:115)
at org.jbehave.core.embedder.Embedder.generateReportsView(Embedder.java:249)
at org.jbehave.core.embedder.Embedder.generateReportsView(Embedder.java:237)
at org.jbehave.core.embedder.Embedder.runStoriesAsPaths(Embedder.java:213)
at org.jbehave.core.junit.JUnitStories.run(JUnitStories.java:20)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:127)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

The story and steps themselves are from the following link:

https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/06/jbehave-configuration-tutorial/

with the following config:

```
import org.jbehave.core.junit.JUnitStories;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class simpleBDD extends JUnitStories {

public simpleBDD() {
    super();
    this.configuredEmbedder().candidateSteps().add(new ExampleSteps());

    org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator.configure();
}

@Override
public List<String> storyPaths(){
    return Arrays.asList("JBehave/Math.story");
}
}
```

This is a maven project, my pom looks likes this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.dh</groupId>
<artifactId>dataloader</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbehave-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.9.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
        <version>0.98.4-hadoop2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-server</artifactId>
        <version>0.98.4-hadoop2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.couchbase.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>couchbase-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This exception is killing me, I've tried many different configurations but still the same error. Googling the file it's complaining about gives me no answers...

Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong? (please assume no knowledge of java, maven and intellij)

Comment: Actually, if you look at the source code at https://github.com/jbehave/jbehave-core/blob/master/jbehave-core/src/main/java/org/jbehave/core/reporters/TemplateableViewGenerator.java that exception is caught and logged but the code is allowed to continue. Are you sure it's actually failing?

Answer (score 2):

Solved! The problem was caused by my .story file not being copied over to the target test-classes folder as it wasn't in the resources folder. As JBehave couldn't find the story file the storyDurations.props wasn't created as no stories were run.

Once I moved the .story file into resources everything ran fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of such an issue and *JBehave* have been always able to write the story durations property file when the Stroy gets exceuted.

In addition, the error seems to be OS specific more that a bug or an issue within *JBehave*, thus a Windows OS.

Check the needed permission and the disk (`C:\`) you are trying to it the best I can suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I tried so many ways, but still didn't solved my issue. Finally I removed spaces and wildcard characters from my path(including folder names), then its allowed me to execute Test Runner.